# Select * from table_name where distinct

Tags: sql, postgresql

Suppose I have a table with column `position` and 10 rows with values:
[1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 4, 3, 2].

How do I select * from that table with **only 1** row for each position?

I use Postgresql, and If I use limit 1 it returns only 1 value (obviously) and I need 1 value of each position with order by create_date field.

Comment: Check the documentation...https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-tutorial/postgresql-select-distinct/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I select * from that table with only 1 row for each position? I
> use Postgresql, and If I use limit 1 it returns only 1 value
> (obviously) and I need 1 value of each position with order by
> create_date field.

You can do it using DISTINCT Keyword.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (position) *
FROM your_table
ORDER BY position, create_date DESC;
```

This will select one row per unique value in the `position` column with the most recent `create_date`

Answer (score 0):

It can be done using **GROUP BY** of `position` Column and then **ORDER BY** of `position` and `create_date`.

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_name 
GROUP BY position 
ORDER BY position, create_date;
```

Comment: That would lead to an error if there are columns that do not show up in the group clause and columns that have not been aggragated.

Comment: I can't run this query, it leads to error "Column create_date must be either aggregated, or mentioned in GROUP BY clause "